# Конфликт pcap.h и stdio.h

Tags: c++, c, qt, pcap, libpcap

Заранее оговорю, что я только начинаю изучать c++. Спасибо за понимание.
Использую QT на Windows, использую pcap, но при включении библиотеки(#include <pcap.h>), выдает ошибки(приведены ниже, заранее извиняюсь, что в такой форме..)
Как я понял, stdio.h и pcap-stdinc.h конфликтуют в методах _snprintf и _vsnprintf, т.к. pcap подключает сам библиотеку stdio.

Часть файла pcap-stdinc.h

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1500
#define snprintf _snprintf
#define vsnprintf _vsnprintf
#define strdup _strdup
#endif



C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdio.h:735: ошибка: conflicting declaration of 'int _snprintf(char*, size_t, const char*, ...)' with 'C' linkage
In file included from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap/pcap.h:60,
                 from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap.h:45,
                 from ..\PCAP_SENDER\main.cpp:1:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:735:23: error: conflicting declaration of 'int _snprintf(char*, size_t, const char*, ...)' with 'C' linkage

C:\Qt\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h:42: In file included from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap/pcap.h:42,
In file included from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap/pcap.h:42,
                 from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap.h:45,
                 from ..\PCAP_SENDER\main.cpp:1:
C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap-stdinc.h:64:18: note: previous declaration with 'C++' linkage
 #define snprintf _snprintf
                  ^~~~~~~~~
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\stdio.h:737: ошибка: conflicting declaration of 'int _vsnprintf(char*, size_t, const char*, va_list)' with 'C' linkage
In file included from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap/pcap.h:60,
                 from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap.h:45,
                 from ..\PCAP_SENDER\main.cpp:1:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:737:23: error: conflicting declaration of 'int _vsnprintf(char*, size_t, const char*, va_list)' with 'C' linkage
   _CRTIMP int __cdecl _vsnprintf(char * __restrict__ _Dest,size_t _Count,const char * __restrict__ _Format,va_list _Args) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Qt\WpdPack\Include\pcap\pcap.h:42: In file included from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap/pcap.h:42,
In file included from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap/pcap.h:42,
                 from C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap.h:45,
                 from ..\PCAP_SENDER\main.cpp:1:
C:/Qt/WpdPack/Include/pcap-stdinc.h:65:19: note: previous declaration with 'C++' linkage
 #define vsnprintf _vsnprintf
                   ^~~~~~~~~~

C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\cstdio:175: ошибка: '::snprintf' has not been declared
In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6361,
                 from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/string:52,
                 from ..\PCAP_SENDER\main.cpp:4:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cstdio:175:11: error: '::snprintf' has not been declared
   using ::snprintf;
           ^~~~~~~~

C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\cstdio:178: ошибка: '::vsnprintf' has not been declared
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cstdio:178:11: error: '::vsnprintf' has not been declared
   using ::vsnprintf;
           ^~~~~~~~~

C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\cstdio:185: ошибка: '__gnu_cxx::snprintf' has not been declared
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cstdio:185:22: error: '__gnu_cxx::snprintf' has not been declared
   using ::__gnu_cxx::snprintf;
                      ^~~~~~~~
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\cstdio:188: ошибка: '__gnu_cxx::vsnprintf' has not been declared
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cstdio:188:22: error: '__gnu_cxx::vsnprintf' has not been declared
   using ::__gnu_cxx::vsnprintf;
                      ^~~~~~~~~

C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:6415: ошибка: 'vsnprintf' is not a member of 'std'
In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/string:52,
                 from ..\PCAP_SENDER\main.cpp:4:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h: In function 'std::__cxx11::string std::__cxx11::to_string(int)':
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6415:50: error: 'vsnprintf' is not a member of 'std'
   { return __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<string>(&std::vsnprintf, 4 * sizeof(int),
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6415:50: note: suggested alternative: 'isprint'
   { return __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<string>(&std::vsnprintf, 4 * sizeof(int),
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~
                                                  isprint
```

Comment: При использовании mingw эта часть должна игнорироваться. Посмотри что за код в указанных строках

Comment: Даже когда кода нет, просто include pcap.h, то вылезает это..